Exception Type: ValueError: node array from the pickle has an incompatible dtype
So I copied a DjangoML project from Github. The ML model is essentially a diagnosis system that predicts whether or not a patient is at risk based on the values of their blood tests.
I'm running this project locally in VSCode but have yet to deploy the backend/ML model.
I encountered this problem while attempting to forecast the outcome in the web browser.
I'm using Python 3.11.0 for this project.
The requirements.txt file includes:

 asgiref==3.5.0

 Django==4.0.3

  joblib==1.1.0

 numpy~=1.26.4

 pandas==2.2.2

 python-dateutil==2.8.2

 pytz==2022.1

 scikit-learn==1.0.2

 scipy==1.8.0

 six==1.16.0

 sklearn==0.0

 sqlparse==0.4.2 

threadpoolctl==3.1.0 

tzdata==2021.5 

 `Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\Django_MachineLearning_HealthcareApp-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner response = get_response(request) 

File "D:\Django_MachineLearning_HealthcareApp-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\Django_MachineLearning_HealthcareApp-main\backend\views.py", line 76, in lpredictor result = ValuePredictor(llis, 7, mname) 

File "D:\Django_MachineLearning_HealthcareApp-main\backend\views.py", line 60, in ValuePredictor trained_model = joblib.load(rf'{mdname}_model.pkl') 

File "D:\Django_MachineLearning_HealthcareApp-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 658, in load obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode) 

File "D:\Django_MachineLearning_HealthcareApp-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 577, in _unpickle obj = unpickler.load()

File "C:\Users\vanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\pickle.py", line 1213, in load dispatch[key[0]](self)

File "D:\Django_MachineLearning_HealthcareApp-main\venv\Lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 402, in load_build Unpickler.load_build(self)

File "C:\Users\vang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\pickle.py", line 1718, in load_build setstate(state) File "sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx", line 865, in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree.setstate <source code not available>

File "sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx", line 1571, in sklearn.tree._tree._check_node_ndarray <source code not available>

Exception Type: ValueError at /diagnose/liver/report

Exception Location:sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx, line 1571, in sklearn.tree._tree._check_node_ndarray Exception Value: node array from the pickle has an incompatible dtype:

expected: {'names': ['left_child', 'right_child', 'feature', 'threshold', 'impurity', 'n_node_samples', 'weighted_n_node_samples', 'missing_go_to_left'], 'formats': ['<i8', '<i8', '<i8', '<f8', '<f8', '<i8', '<f8', 'u1'], 'offsets': [0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56], 'itemsize': 64}

got     : [('left_child', '<i8'), ('right_child', '<i8'), ('feature', '<i8'), ('threshold', '<f8'), ('impurity', '<f8'), ('n_node_samples', '<i8'), ('weighted_n_node_samples', '<f8')] `

I'm a rookie in Python and machine learning and will appreciate any help and explanation on this.

Please include a minimal reproducible example so that SO members can help you find potential errors. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
The error messages shown seem to be dataset/code-related corresponding to lines of a larger code. In case you cannot share your code, have a look at the package documentation (including examples) and available vignettes as a starting point.

It seems that you are trying to unpickle a model trained and pickled with older versions of scikit-learn and joblib. The format of models pickled by joblib changed recently and the compatibility with older files has been broken as a result.
The solution is simply to downgrade your version of those packages to match the correct version. Most likely this is scikit-learn==1.0.2 and joblib==1.1.0 as specified in the requirements you posted.
You may have to downgrade your version of Python too actually, because scikit-learn 1.0.2 seems to require python 3.10 (not 3.11)

After searching several posts, this is the only solution that worked! Thanks!

@Etienne Ok, but what if we have a pickle file made with a new version that cannot be opened with the old version? What if my script needs to use both pickle files? Also, why was this backwards compatibility broken? Was it a mistake or something planned?

@acampove As a general advice, the best would be to use a virtual environment (like Virtualenv or Anaconda) to avoid this kind of situation altogether. Package version management can lead to huge headaches when compatibility starts to break (which will happen sooner or later). Now to answer your question, I guess you could try to import different versions of the package dynamically. Not sure how that can be done though... As to why exactly compatibility was broken, your guess is as good as mine. Scikit-learn just doesn't guarantee this kind of compatibility

I am using conda, but the problem here is that scikit-learn broke compatibility with old versions. i.e. If you train and save the model with an old version, you cannot open those models with new versions. So either we are stuck with an ancient version, which is unmanageable, or we retrain everything, every time we upgrade scikit-learn, which is very wasteful. I do not understand how a project that is used by so many people has such a poor support for serialization. How aren't we investing more money and time on making sure these things work?
